# How to return a list of serializable XML elements

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api

I know how to make function return a "pretty" result as xml, and I want just that, but without the extra parent element.

Using this function

```
[HttpGet]
public XElement MyFunction() { ... }
```

gets me half way. I get this:

```
<Result>
    <row>
        <cell>...</cell>
        <cell>...</cell>
        <cell>...</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>...</cell>
        <cell>...</cell>
        <cell>...</cell>
    </row>
</Result>
```

I want result like this:

```
<row>
    <cell>...</cell>
    <cell>...</cell>
    <cell>...</cell>
</row>
<row>
    <cell>...</cell>
    <cell>...</cell>
    <cell>...</cell>
</row>
```

And using function like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<XElement> MyFunction() { ... }
```

Gets me a result like this:

```
<ArrayOfXElement 
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Xml.Linq">
    <XElement>
        <row xmlns="">
            <cell>...</cell>
            <cell>...</cell>
            <cell>...</cell>
        </row>
    </XElement>
    <XElement>
        <row xmlns="">
            <cell>...</cell>
            <cell>...</cell>
            <cell>...</cell>
        </row>
    </XElement>
    etc...
```

Which is, I mean... look at it... its hideous.

I beleave that there must be a simple solution to this, or at least a workaround.

**EDIT** As @Fabio suggested in the first comment, XML is invalid if it has no root element, and thus, this question becomes silly, since I do need other systems to be able to read the result of my functions. Even so, I will not remove this question, because I hope that somebody else who needs a solution like this will, like me, realise that that kind of XML document is invalid. Also, if anyone answers the question, I will approve the answer.

Comment: Structure without root element is invalid XML format. You can create manually file without root element but standard Xml parsers will not be available to parse it

Answer (score 0):

get a reader and get the innerXml. This should get you what you need.

```
   var MainElement= XElementA.CreateReader();
    MainElement.MoveToContent();

    var Content=MainElement.ReadInnerXml();
```

Comment: I understood the concept, but I couldn't find `XElementA` nor `CreateReader` in any library nor in `XElement` class.

Comment: I using XElementA as a variable, representing an instance of the XElement Class.  CreateReader is a method for XElement class in the System.XML.Linq NameSpace. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.createreader(v=vs.110).aspx